# Can't install PHP Package on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, php

I am having trouble re-installing PHP via yum on my server hosted by digital ocean.

I had PHP 5.4 installed but wanted 5.6. I added/enabled the remi repo's, ran `yum -y remove php*` and then tried to re-install php.

When I run `yum -y install php` I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * remi: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-php56: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.8-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.8-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-zip(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php-common-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.8-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.7-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.12.5-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.6.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/

I'm a bit stuck. I have tried removing httpd, re-installing httpd, nothing seems to fix this. I even get the error when I disable remi and try and install PHP 5.4.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

I think this could be an issue to do with repositories because I was able to install php56 on a fresh server without any issues at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running EL7, but you installed the remi repostiory for EL6. Install the correct repo and try again.

Comment: I removed all of the repo's apart from centos ones and then following this tutorial: https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

I got this result: http://pastebin.com/y8snscmt

Comment: If you want to go off and do your own thing, that's fine, but then why ask the question?

Comment: Sorry Michael, I did read it. I'm not great at Linux and I thought you meant I had installed the wrong version of epel. I am grateful for your help...

Comment: I managed to get EL7 installed and it still wasn't working. After that I tried a `yum clean`, `yum update` then removed httpd, installed it again and then php56w was able to install.
Thank you for your help!